# Как корректно рассчитать R2, RMSE для полиномиальной регрессии scikit-learn?

Tags: python, sklearn

Мне нужно сделать определенный прогноз (количество mentor при увеличении количества mentee).

Для этого я использую полиномиальную регрессию из scikit-learn.
Данные не соответствуют нормальному распределению. Для модели большее значение имеют более поздние значения (поэтому важно, чтобы модель не давала большие ошибки при больших значениях).
График с показателями.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В данных есть выбросы (выбросы оставляю, так как это более поздние показатели).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Судя по всему, одну из этих моделей можно использовать прогноза.

```
x = df_for_pred['mentee_cnt'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
y = df_for_pred['mentor_cnt'].to_numpy()

# Разбивка на тренировочную и тестовую выборки
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

degrees = [2, 3, 4, 5]

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))
for i in range(len(degrees)):
    ax = plt.subplot(1, len(degrees), i+1)

    polynomial_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=degrees[i])
    linear_regression = LinearRegression()
    # преобразование x_train
    x_degree = polynomial_features.fit_transform(x_train)
    # обучение модели
    linear_regression = linear_regression.fit(x_degree, y_train)
    # изменение x_test
    x_fit = np.arange(x_test.min(), x_test.max(), 1)[:, np.newaxis]
    y_pred = linear_regression.predict(polynomial_features.fit_transform(x_fit))

    x_test_degree = polynomial_features.fit_transform(x_train)

#    r2 = r2_score()
#    rmse = mean_squared_error(, squared=False)
#    mse = mean_squared_error()

    plt.scatter(x_test, y_test, label="Values")

    plt.plot(x_fit, y_pred, label='model', color='r')

    plt.title(f"Model degree ={i+1}")
    plt.xlabel("mentee")
    plt.ylabel("mentor")
    plt.xticks()
    plt.yticks()
    plt.legend(loc="best")
    plt.grid(False)

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как рассчитать R2, RMSE, MSE? По идее нужно рассчитать эти показатели для y_test и y_pred, но из-за преобразования данных эта задача усложнилась.